# C# & SQL Server : SqlCommand not reading commas around int value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I’m trying to execute a simple insert into statement and I'm running into an error at the value of one of my parameters. It’s having this weird issue where it refuses to have commas before and after it.

```
    String s = "insert into Orders(customerID,orderDate,orderTotal,quantity,contents) values(@custID,@orderDate,@total,@quantity,@contents)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, c);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", Int32.Parse(custID));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderDate",DateTime.Now);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", Globals.cartTotal);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", cartList.Items.Count);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contents", cartContents);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The values that are currently trying to be added are:

```
    '100','4/28/2018 2:50:49AM','42.97','3','album1, album2, album3'
```

The `SqlException` is thrown at the value 3, and when I hover over the `String s` value while debugging to see what was saved in it, it shows as this:

```
    '100','4/28/2018 2:50:49AM','42.97'3'album1, album2, album3'
```

Notice that 3 is a stand-alone value with no ,' before it and no ', after it. I thought maybe it was because it was an `int` data type but `custID` was parsed to an `int` and read just fine. What is this strange issue??

Comment: This is what you see when you hover over the code : `,'42.97'3'album1, album2, album3'` You are missing 2 commas which should be like this `,'42.97',3,'album1, album2, album3'`

Comment: @Tomm How is that even possible when I literally wrote it as `@total,`?

Comment: @Tomm I even hard-coded the commas to make sure they were in there and they weren’t even read either

Comment: Can you please post what SQLException you are getting? Also on hovering on mouse on String "s" should not display parsed value in debug mode. "s" should be as it is with @parameter names. On running `ExecuteNonQuery` will call insert statement in `sp_executesql` with parameters separately.. so i think issue is something else.

Comment: @par An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll. Additional information: incorrect syntax near '3';

Comment: @par I’m just really confused because I used this exact same code in another form for a register page, adding a user into a different table in my database and i didn’t have this issue.

Comment: @AlyssaJune I have no clue how this is not working... Everything seems to be correct.

Comment: @AlyssaJune , also check trace in SQL profiler to see if anything wrong from SQL or even query reaching to SQL or not. i mean exception coming before sending query to SQL or not.

Comment: @AlyssaJune is this error the output of a try catch ? If not check if anything else outputs from the try catch, and is every value returning to the correct form it should be as in int string etc.

Comment: It suddenly worked. I have no idea how but it just worked. Lol thanks anyway guys